# Add Todo in Redux, cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm going to add an object to the array, the second time I want to add another object the whole array becomes number one and I end up with an error, my goal is to add a task to program Todo with Redux. 
I also get this errors:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
> TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

//todoReducer.js

```
import {ADD_TODO} from '../Actions/Todo';

const initialState = {
  todos:[],
};


const handleAddTodo = (state, action) => {
  const {todos} = state;
 
  const newTodo =[...todos, {
    id: todos.length + 1,
    text: action.title,
    isComplete: false,
  }]
  return (
    todos.push(newTodo)
  )
}

export default function todoRDS(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return handleAddTodo(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your return function you return wrong value. You need to return the state

```
const handleAddTodo = (state, action) => {
  const {todos} = state;
 
  return {
...state,
todos: [...todos, {
    id: todos.length + 1,
    text: action.title,
    isComplete: false,
  }]
}
}
```

Comment: state ->  action ->  {type: "ADD_TODO", title: "task 4"}

Comment: todos: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, title: "task 1", isComplete: false}
1: {id: 2, title: "task 2", isComplete: false}
2: {id: 3, title: "task 3", isComplete: false}
length: 3

Comment: I don't know what you want to say ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
export default function todoRDS(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO:
      return {...state, todos: [...state.todos, { id: state.todos.length +1, title: action.title, isComplete: false }] }
    default:
      return state
  }

}
```

state is unmutable in react and redux you need to create a new state with old state values and add your new todo inside that new object. If you still want to use handeAddTodo try this:

const handleAddTodo = (state, action) => {
return {...state, todos: [...state.todos, { id: state.todos.length +1, title: action.title, isComplete: false }] }
}

Comment: Can u specify the problem when you try to add first 3 todos were there any error ? Where do you try to show your todos.

Comment: [A photo of the output result](http://s11.picofile.com/file/8405402768/state.png)
, I showed state in the console section

Comment: Okay from what I understand u are tryin to console.log your older state so when you dispatch an action the state that you console.log is the older state. That is why u are using it to create new state and adding another todo actually. So if you want to console.log your new state do it in another place. For instance load your todos in a components console.log(todos) and check the todos after you add another todo check it again. Or you can add redux devtools extension and check your state directly from there.

Comment: Basically, to see your new state go to the component where you add your todo. Use useSelector(if you are using hooks) or map state to props (if you are using class component) and console.log your todos there you will see it has all the properties.